# jQuery Tabs - Adding reusable next/previous buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

Im looking to extend the jquery tabs to add next and previous buttons - which i have done using the show event. The problem is that its a big chunk of code added to that event for each page that needs tabs and these buttons. How i go about making it a reusable component?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a jquery plugin to wire your tabs up by convention. Here's a tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Decorate your tab list with something like , then have your plugin pick up on ul's with class "scrollable". Write all your logic in there. You shouldn't need to call any function explicitly for each page.